# laravel update without passing ID

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I am working on a ticket log where tickets get edited multiple times before they are 'done'.

I have an overview where you see all the tickets, on top of the page are 6 buttons. All buttons open a popup with a form. The first button is a create function which makes the ticket and fills in the first information. All other fields are now `NULL`. The second buttons is the first edit button.

Upon opening it opens an form where the user scans a barcode to fill in the first field; `Ticket Number`. this ticket number is unique for every Ticket. Next thing to fill in is your credentials, which come from a dropdown.

Due to the fact that all the edit forms work by Ticket_number (which is scanned from a QR code) I made it so all forms are on the same page. Therefor I am not able to do something like : `action="{{ route('countries.update',$country->id) }}`  as I don't know the ID at this moment.

Here is the code behind everything(and you can see what I tried there too):

web.php:

```
 //    TICKET LOG ROUTES
 Route::post('ticket/start-picking', 'TicketController@startpicking')->name('tickets.startpicking');
 Route::resource('tickets', 'TicketController');
```

form for edit:

```
<div id="modal-start-picking" class="modal">
    <form method="POST" id="modal-start-picking-form" action="{{ route('tickets.startpicking') }}">
        @csrf
        <input type="text" value="modal-start-picking" name="type" hidden>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>Start Picking</h4>
            <p>Scan Ticket Number here</p>
            <div class="input-field">
                <label for="start">Ticket Number</label>
                <input type="text" name="ticket_number" id="start" autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <select id="picker" name="picker">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a Picker</option>
                    @foreach($employees as $employee)
                        <option {{(old('picker') == $employee->initials ) ? 'selected' : ''}} value="{{ $employee->initials }}">{{ $employee->initials }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input class="btn-flat" type="submit" value="Start Picking">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Function in TicketController:

```
public function startpicking(Request $request, Ticket $ticket)
{
    $request->validate([
        'picker' => 'required',
    ]);

    $ticket->update(array_merge($request->all(), ['picker_start_time' => Carbon::now()]));
    return redirect()->route('tickets.index')->with('toast', 'Ticket updated successfully');
}
```

If any more info is required I Will gladly update my post.

Comment: How is it possible to edit a non existent ticket? What I mean by that is if there is no ticket, they surely can't edit it right? if the ticket exists, pass the id onclick of the edit button to your edit form somehow

Comment: The thing is that the ID isn't known yet. I think this has to happen in the controller. Only the ticket number (which also is unique) is known in the form. I basically want to skip one of the `public function edit(Ticket $ticket)` and go straight to update.

Comment: how do you want to go to update action without a unique identifier to fetch the records that are being updated ?

Comment: The ticket number is my unique identifier. They can not be the same in any of the tickets ever made. @Leorent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how it's done.

```
$request->validate([
    'picker' => 'required',
]);
Ticket::where('ticket_number', $posted_ticket_number)->update([
    'picker'            => $request->picker,
    'picker_start_time' => Carbon::now(),
]);
```

You just have to use `::where('column', 'variable')`.

The variable was pulled from my form (The Ticket number in my case. As this was an unique identifier.) and the column is self explanatory.